# TypeError: dispatch is not a function in nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Trying to dispatch a delete event from a button inside a nested component.

I passed the dispatch as a property to the component from App.js like so

```
render() {
        const {files, isFetching, dispatch} = this.props;
        const isEmpty = files.length === 0;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Uploadr</h1>
                {isEmpty
                    ? (isFetching ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <h2>No files.</h2>)
                    : <div style={{opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1}}>
                        <Files files={files} dispatch={dispatch}/>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Inside the nested component I call dispatch from an `onclick` attribute

```
const Files = ({files, dispatch}) => (
    <ul>
        {files.map((file, i) =>
            <li key={i}>{file.name}
                <button onClick={dispatch(deleteFileById(file.id))}>Delete</button>
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>
);

Files.propTypes = {
    files: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Files
```

This is the method being called

```
export const deleteFileById = (dispatch, fileId) => {
    dispatch(deleteFile);
    return fetch(`/api/files/${fileId}`, {method : 'delete'})
        .then(dispatch(fetchFiles(dispatch)))
};
```

I tried doing `this.props.dispatch` however this did not work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `() => dispatch(deleteFileById)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your method `deleteFileById` expects the dispatcher as an argument.
Does the following adjustment work for you?

```
<button onClick={() => (deleteFileById(dispatch, file.id))}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: this should work. I'm about to post the same answer.

Comment: slightly off topic but I like your profile picture @tomaytotomato ! hl3 confirmed ? ;-)

Comment: If I can get this react app working, then I will personally convince Gabe Newell to release the game.

Comment: if you can convince gaben, I will personally develop the react app for you ;-)